# Upgrading Ruby using homebrew on a mac and installing berkshelp

Tags: ruby, homebrew, berkshelf, homebrew-cask

I just finished upgrading my ruby to fit the requirements for berkshelf... at least so i thought... and now when i try to implement berkshelf i throw this error:

```
ruby-build: use openssl from homebrew
Downloading ruby-2.3.1.tar.bz2...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.3/ruby-2.3.1.tar.bz2
Installing ruby-2.3.1...
Installed ruby-2.3.1 to /Users/meee/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1

meee$ sudo gem install berkshelf
Password:
ERROR:  Error installing berkshelf:
    buff-extensions requires Ruby version >= 2.2.0.
```

Has anyone encountered this problem before?

I'm running the newest sierra os build.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are installing ruby for user `meee`, but berkshelf for root. It won't work. You should use user ruby all the time.
2. Maybe use [ChefDK](https://downloads.chef.io/chefdk), it has berkshelf included and probably all other tools you might need for chef.